# qemu x86_64 enable protect mode and jmp far, causes reboot

Tags: x86, operating-system, qemu

I'm trying to achieve a bootloader and I open the A20 bus and set the GDT, and enable protect mode, when I try to jump far segment, the qemu was reboot. The code follows:

```
%macro SEG_ASM 3      
    dw ((%3) & 0xffff), ((%2) & 0xffff)  
    db (((%2) >> 16) & 0xff), (0x90 | (%1)),  (0xc0 | (((%3) >> 16) & 0xf)), (((%2) >> 24) & 0xff)
%endmacro

%define STA_X       0x8        
%define STA_E       0x4       
%define STA_C       0x4    
%define STA_W       0x2     
%define STA_R       0x2   
%define STA_A       0x1 

CS_SELECTOR equ 0x8
DS_SELECTOR equ 0x10
VIDEO_SELECTOR equ 0x18

org 0x7e00

[bits 16]
    
    ; Fast A20
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 0x2
    out 0x92, al

    ; load GDT
    lgdt [GDT_Description]
    mov eax, GDT
    ; enable protect mode
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x00000001
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CS_SELECTOR:p_mode_start

    
[bits 32]
p_mode_start:      

    jmp $


align 4        

GDT:           
NULL_SEG:     
    dd 0, 0
CODE_SEG:
    SEG_ASM (STA_X | STA_R), 0x0, 0xFFFFF   ;base = 0x0, limit = 0xFFFFF

; DATA_SEG:
;     SEG_ASM STA_W, 0x0, 0xFFFFF             ;base = 0x0, limit = 0xFFFFF

; VIDEO_SEG:
;     SEG_ASM STA_W,  0xB8000,0x7

GDT_SIZE equ $ - GDT
GDT_LIMIT equ GDT_SIZE - 1

GDT_Description:
    dw GDT_LIMIT
    dd GDT
```

In fact, when I was Single step debugging using gdb, 'jmp $' can be located, but when I enter 'c' to continue, the qemu was rebooted.

```
=> 0x7e23:      jmp    0x7e23
   0x7e25:      nop
   0x7e26:      nop
   0x7e27:      nop
   0x7e28:      add    %al,(%rax)
```

Using bochs to debug, the debug information followed:

```
<bochs:2> b *0x7e00
<bochs:3> c
(0) Breakpoint 1, 0x00007e00 in ?? ()
Next at t=17406037
(0) [0x000000007e00] 0000:7e00 (unk. ctxt): in al, 0x92               ; e492
<bochs:4> s
Next at t=17406038
(0) [0x000000007e02] 0000:7e02 (unk. ctxt): or al, 0x02               ; 0c02
<bochs:5>
Next at t=17406039
(0) [0x000000007e04] 0000:7e04 (unk. ctxt): out 0x92, al              ; e692
<bochs:6>
Next at t=17406040
(0) [0x000000007e06] 0000:7e06 (unk. ctxt): lgdt ds:0x7e40            ; 0f0116407e
<bochs:7>
Next at t=17406041
(0) [0x000000007e0b] 0000:7e0b (unk. ctxt): xor eax, eax              ; 6631c0
<bochs:8>
Next at t=17406042
(0) [0x000000007e0e] 0000:7e0e (unk. ctxt): mov eax, cr0              ; 0f20c0
<bochs:9>
Next at t=17406043
(0) [0x000000007e11] 0000:7e11 (unk. ctxt): or eax, 0x00000001        ; 6683c801
<bochs:10>
Next at t=17406044
(0) [0x000000007e15] 0000:7e15 (unk. ctxt): mov cr0, eax              ; 0f22c0
<bochs:11>
Next at t=17406045
(0) [0x000000007e18] 0000:00007e18 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0x0008:7e1d          ; ea1d7e0800
<bochs:12> n
Next at t=17406046
(0) [0x000000007e1d] 0008:00007e1d (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2 (0x00007e1d)      ; ebfe
<bochs:13>
Next at t=17406047
(0) [0x000000007e1d] 0008:00007e1d (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2 (0x00007e1d)      ; ebfe
<bochs:14> s
Next at t=17406048
(0) [0x000000007e1d] 0008:00007e1d (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2 (0x00007e1d)      ; ebfe
<bochs:15>
Next at t=17406049
(0) [0x000000007e1d] 0008:00007e1d (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2 (0x00007e1d)      ; ebfe
<bochs:16> c
(0).[17581239] [0x000000007e1d] 0008:00007e1d (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2 (0x00007e1d)      ; ebfe
Next at t=17581240
(0) [0x0000fffffff0] f000:fff0 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0xf000:e05b          ; ea5be000f0
<bochs:17>
```

When I enter 'c' to continue, the machine reboot.

Comment: BOCHS has a good built-in debugger that should be able to tell you exactly why the machine rebooted.  (e.g. what faults were involved in a triple fault, and can parse GDT entries to make sure you have what you intended.)

Comment: I'm trying to use bochs to debug, but the same error appeared, the debug information show on question, and I have no idea about this error.

Comment: It looks like you're in your infinite loop, so the fault must have been something asynchronous.  Perhaps a timer interrupt? Is your IDT set up correctly?  (What even happens if you enter protected mode with interrupts enabled, but haven't done an lidt yet?)  I thought BOCHs would be able to show you exactly why a reboot happened, but I haven't done osdev stuff with it myself.

Comment: I'm with Peter, the issue id likely that you didn't do a CLI to disable interrupts. You can only enable interrupts once you have created an IDT.

Comment: Thank you very mush, the  problem was solved when I do a cli before jmp $. the Interrupt handling mechanism are different during protect mode and real mode, so I need cli before reset IDT, Is that right？ Thank you a lot, this question has troubled me for a long time and finally got an answer

Comment: You should put the CLI before you enter protected mode. If you get an interrupt after entering protected mode but before the JMP $ it could crash.